# Is it possible to access and set the "File is ready for archiving" flag with PHP in Windows?

Tags: php, windows, file, attributes

If I make a file like this:
[image]

and then go to it's properties and click advance (I removed the location):
[image]

is it possible for me to toggle this flag:
[image]

with PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
exec("attrib +A file.txt");
```

Comment: As far as i know, yes. You may be able to use PHP's COM Class, but i dont have any experience with it.